# creating a map fragment along with other fragments in an app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Am trying to create and app with one activity but multiple fragment. to achieve this i have created the Main Activity and set a View-pager in its layout file.

The main Activity connect to the internet via its Ascyn Task download the required information stores it in an Array-list which will be used to fill out data on the Three Main fragments(Map Fragment, List-fragment,Augmented Reality-Fragment) the issue am having is that for some reason the map will not display it gives me a null pointer before I even load the data.

**Edit** I have made some changes as suggested by @Roman. I still have some issues with my `OnResume` method.

**EDIT 2** I have made a bit of progress. I don't get the null pointer any more at the same time the map still isn't displaying instead i just have a blank screen.

**EDIT 3  FIXED**

```
public class MapDisplayFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements
    OnInfoWindowClickListener {

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UplacesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
static List<Float> fmyLat = new ArrayList<Float>();
static List<Float> fmyLng = new ArrayList<Float>();
HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
public static final String placesListItems = "ArrayList";
public static final String myLAt = "myLAt";
public static final String myLng = "myLng";
public static String User_lat = "user_lat";
public static String User_lng = "user_lng";
public static String KEY_REFRENCE = "refrence";
public static String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vivinity";
public static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

private static String[] marker_Id;
private static String[] refrences;
public static String ref;
private GoogleMap mMap;
FragmentTransaction view;
// View mView;
ViewGroup layout;
MapView mView;
double Ulat = 0.0;
double Ulng = 0.0;
Marker FourSquare;
Marker User;
String Reference = "";

LatLng ULatLng;
GLSurfaceView mGLView;
Location userLoc;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
    mView.onResume();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    Log.d("OnResume View", "Sucess");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Destroy MEthod", "Sucess");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.gc();
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment,
            container, false);
    mView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setMapTransparent(layout);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    Log.d("OnCreate View", "Sucess");
    return layout;
}

private void setMapTransparent(ViewGroup group) {
    int childCount = group.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) child);
        } else if (child instanceof SurfaceView) {
            child.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        mMap = mView.getMap();

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }

        setUpMap();
    }

    else {
        setUpMap();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void setUpMap() {

    Ulat = getArguments().getDouble(User_lat);
    Ulng = getArguments().getDouble(User_lng);
    userLoc = new Location("manaul");
    userLoc.setLatitude(Ulat);
    userLoc.setLongitude(Ulng);
    Log.d("uwer LAt", String.valueOf(Ulat));

    UplacesListItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getArguments()
            .get(placesListItems);
    if (UplacesListItems.size() != 0) {

        Log.d("ArrayList", String.valueOf(UplacesListItems.size()));

    } else {
        Log.d("ArrayList", "ArrayList = null");
    }

    mMap = mView.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // AddUser();

    if (UplacesListItems.size() != 0) {
        addMarkersToMap();

    }
    mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(Ulat, Ulng), 15));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void addMarkersToMap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UplacesListItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getArguments()
            .get(placesListItems);
    fmyLat = (List<Float>) getArguments().get(myLAt);
    fmyLng = (List<Float>) getArguments().get(myLng);

    double flat;
    double flng;

    if (UplacesListItems != null) {

        marker_Id = new String[UplacesListItems.size()];
        refrences = new String[UplacesListItems.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < UplacesListItems.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("lat of fourSquarePlaces", String.valueOf(fmyLat.get(0)));

            song = UplacesListItems.get(i);
            flat = fmyLat.get(i);
            flng = fmyLng.get(i);
            Location destination = new Location("manual");
            destination.setLatitude(flat);
            destination.setLongitude(flng);
            // System.out.print(fPLat);

            // StoreReference(song.get(KEY_REFRENCE));

            if (mMap != null) {

                ULatLng = new LatLng(flat, flng);

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

                final String distance = String.valueOf(df
                        .format(destination.distanceTo(userLoc) / 1000))
                        + "Km";
                final String Reference = (song.get(KEY_REFRENCE));
                final String category = (song.get(KEY_CATEGORY));

                FourSquare = mMap
                        .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(ULatLng)
                                .title(song.get(KEY_NAME))
                                .snippet(
                                        distance + " " + Reference + " "
                                                + category)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.point_map)));
                marker_Id[i] = FourSquare.getId();
                refrences[i] = song.get(KEY_REFRENCE);
                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        View v = ((Activity) getActivity())
                                .getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                        R.layout.custom_info_windows, null);
                        TextView name = (TextView) v
                                .findViewById(R.id.name);

                        TextView Distance = (TextView) v
                                .findViewById(R.id.distance);
                        TextView reference = (TextView) v
                                .findViewById(R.id.reference);
                        TextView category = (TextView) v
                                .findViewById(R.id.category);
                        String value = marker.getSnippet();

                        String[] result = value.split(" ", 3);

                        String distanceText = result[0];
                        String referenceText = result[1];
                        String categoryText = result[2];

                        name.setText(marker.getTitle());

                        Distance.setText(distanceText);
                        reference.setText(referenceText);
                        category.setText(categoryText);

                        return v;
                    }

                });
                mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

                Log.d("Add Marker Options Method", "Sucess");

            }

            else {

                // setUpMapIfNeeded();

            }

        }
    } else {

        Log.d("Add Marker Options Method", "ArraryList Empty");
    }

}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String value = marker.getSnippet();

    String[] result = value.split(" ", 3);
    String referenceText = result[1];
    String categoryText = result[2];
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleFragmentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("KEY_REFRENCE", referenceText);
    intent.putExtra("KEY_CATEGORY", categoryText);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

layout

```
 LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:name="mapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi I'm having exact same issue, if you were able to sort this can you please help me to fix, it would be great if you can update the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're declaring

```
<fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView">
```

inside your `MapDisplayFragment`'s layout, meaning you're declaring a nested fragment, which is probably not what you want to do. Also, `<fragment>` tags in anything but activity layouts (e.g. the layout passed to `setContentView`) aren't really supported as far as I know.

Instead, you can add the `MapView` to your fragment's layout directly using:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

You can find docs on using a [MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview).

**REMEMBER**: Don't forget to pass through fragment lifecycle events such as `onCreate`, `onResume`, `onPause` and `onDestroy` to the corresponding methods on the `MapView`.

Second, if you try to call anything like `findFragmentById` or `findViewById` inside `onCreateView` before you return a view, they'll be null because you fragment doesn't have a view herarchy yet. You can instead do something like:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
// Note: rootView.findViewById, not this.findViewById
View foo = rootView.findViewById(foo);
...
return rootView;
```

Comment: thanks tired out your solution but i still get a null pointer. i think my problem is here `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(view.getId()))
                   .getMap();`

Comment: I fixed it i think my problem lies in my on resume method this is what i have done so far `@Override
 public void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  view.onResume();
  super.onResume();
  
  SetupMapIfneeded();

  Log.d("On Resume", "Sucess");
  
 }`

Comment: Ah, are you still using a fragment then? If you've switched to just a MapView, you can just use view.findViewById to find it.

Comment: i dont really understand could you explain more and show me where in my code

Comment: the app runs now but the map is not displayed. any Ideas? my onResume looks like this  `public void onResume()super.onResume();
SetupMapIfneeded();Log.d("On Resume", "Sucess");}`

Comment: Are you calling MapView's onCreate method? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: I took it out it kept giving me errors. how do I call it properly do I use `rootview.findviewByid` or I just call it directly??

Comment: the `oncreate` Method is there but its blank. I took it out because there is nothing to initialize yet. The map is initialized in the `onCreateView` and because of that if i perform the `rootview.findviewByid`it  gives me errors me errors. how do I call it properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
     mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
```

I would say that possibly this line of code generates the null exception. Check in debugger is findFragmentById() is not returning null. In that case, executing the getMap methode on a null object will resolve in a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

//initialize this line on class level

private GoogleMap mapFragment;

put this code inside onCreateView

SupportMapFragment mapFragments = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

mapFragment=mapFragments.getMap();